# How do I call << operator of base class in the derived class

Tags: c++, oop, operator-keyword

I have this [CSVParser](https://ghostplusplus.googlecode.com/svn-history/r555/trunk/ghost/csvparser.cpp) class, I inherited it, and I need to call `<<` operator in my derived class:

```
#include "dbcsv.h"

DbCsv::DbCsv() : CSVParser()
{
}


void addColumn(QString &source, const QString &val, const unsigned int s) // 0:duplicate, 1:unique
{
     CSVParser::<< source.toStdString();
}

void removeColumn(QString &source, const QString &val)
{

}
```

I get this error:

```
dbcsv.cpp: In function 'void addColumn(QString&, const QString&, unsigned int)':
dbcsv.cpp:10: error: expected unqualified-id before '<<' token
dbcsv.cpp: At global scope:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CSVParser::operator<<(source.toStdString());
```

The parentheses are mandatory, this is a function call.

Of course, if you *haven't* overridden `operator<<`, then it's simpler:

```
*this << source.toStdString(); // probably what you want
```

Comment: I get this error now: `dbcsv.cpp: In function 'void addColumn(QString&, const QString&, unsigned int)':
dbcsv.cpp:10: error: cannot call member function 'const CSVParser& CSVParser::operator<<(const std::string&)' without object
dbcsv.cpp: At global scope:`

Comment: Your `addColumn` function is not a member function. You have to make it `void DbCsv::addColumn (...) { ...`, otherwise you do not have a (this) object inside the function to call the operator on. Of course, you have to declare it as a member function within the *class* definition in dbcsv.h as well.

Comment: @JohnB Thank you for the notice, I totally skip it.

Comment: When using brackets i had to use (*this)[myIndex]

Answer (score 1):

Precede `<<` with `operator` and append parentheses. to make `operator<<(whatever)`.

This works for the other bit shift operator, and other operator overloads.